# Importing email data into list stops at 100

Tags: python, list, limit, gmail-api, spyder

I am following the example given in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads

My question is that the threads list stops at 100. There are definitely more than 100 threads in my inbox.  I am using Spyder (Python 3.7).  Is that a Spyder limitation? Because Python can  clearly handle larger lists.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at "nextPageToken" in the thread.list

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list

Comment: Thank you @Paul Lemmons!